# How do I combine these nested if else statements? AWS Quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have an if else statement that is like this:

```
ifelse(Group ='A', ifelse(${A}= 'Yes', ${NewPoints}, {Points}), {Points})
```

What I wanted to do is add another if else statement for Group B, C, D and E. But it is giving me errors whenever I try to combine them all. I think my formula is incorrect.

```
ifelse(Group ='A', ifelse(${A}= 'Yes', ${NewPoints}, {Points}), {Points})
ifelse(Group ='B', ifelse(${B}= 'Yes', ${NewPoints}, {Points}), {Points})
ifelse(Group ='C', ifelse(${C}= 'Yes', ${NewPoints}, {Points}), {Points})
ifelse(Group ='D', ifelse(${D}= 'Yes', ${NewPoints}, {Points}), {Points})
ifelse(Group ='E', ifelse(${E}= 'Yes', ${NewPoints}, {Points}), {Points})
```

How do I combine these into one nested statement?

Comment: This will need nested ifelse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been better with some data and expected output; however, to what I can understand, seems like you need a nested-if.

Refer below the formula and output.

```
ifelse(Group ='A', ifelse({A}= 'Yes', {Newpoints}, {Points}), 
    ifelse(Group ='B', ifelse({B}= 'Yes', {Newpoints}, {Points}), 
        ifelse(Group ='B', ifelse({B}= 'Yes', {Newpoints}, {Points}), 
            ifelse(Group ='C', ifelse({C}= 'Yes', {Newpoints}, {Points}), 
                ifelse(Group ='D', ifelse({D}= 'Yes', {Newpoints}, {Points}), 
                    ifelse(Group ='E', ifelse({E}= 'Yes', {Newpoints}, {Points}), {Points})
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

Will yield following output in a calculated field called - calcf.

[image]